# How do I get the video upload link for uploading a video to my Vimeo account?

Tags: c#, .net-core, vimeo, vimeo-api

How do I get the video upload link for uploading a video to my Vimeo account using the Vimeo API with C# and .Net Core?

Answer will be a method that will be called like this:

```
var vimeoUploadUrl =  await getVimeoUploadUrl(videoFileSizeInBytes, accessToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: [API Reference](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference)

Comment: Again, StackOverflow is not an example repository. A question like this is too broad, and low quality. Take a look at the [help/on-topic] for what kind of questions are a good fit, and review [ask] to understand how to write a good question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do this you have to have a Vimeo account (this works with Plus level or better, don't know about the others), have created a Vimeo app (in Vimeo), given it permission to upload, and gotten an access token. With all that in place, here is the code:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public async Task<string> getVimeoUploadUrl(int videoFileSize, string accessToken)
    {
        var vimeoUploadUrl = "";

        string vimeoApiUrl = "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos"; // Vimeo URL

        try
        {

            string body =
                @"{'upload': {'approach': 'post','size': '" + videoFileSize + "'}}".Replace("'", "\"");

            HttpContent content = new StringContent(body);

            using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, vimeoApiUrl))
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4");
                requestMessage.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
                requestMessage.Content = content;
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                var myJsonObject = JObject.Parse(result);

                vimeoUploadUrl = myJsonObject.SelectToken("upload.upload_link").ToString();                  
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
        // Do your own error handling!   
        }

        return vimeoUploadUrl;

    }
```

Comment: 1) You shouldn't build JSON manually. 2) Your content-type isn't form-encoded, it's JSON.

Comment: @John, thanks for #2, fixed it in the code. Looking into #1.

Comment: 3) You should use ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid dead locks 4) Your exception handling is a nightmare

Comment: @SirRufo, Thank you, I will look into #3 so I know when to apply it an when not to apply it. #4 is what it is for simplicity.

Comment: @SirRufo, "In .NET Core, Microsoft did away with the SynchronizationContext that caused us to need ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere. Thus your ASP.NET Core app technically doesn’t need any ConfigureAwait(false) logic in them because it's redundant. ...if you have a library that is using .NET Standard, then it is highly recommended that you still use .ConfigureAwait(false). ... But if someone with .NET Framework ends up using this library and calls it synchronously, they will be in big trouble." https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/December_2018/async-await-configureawait

Comment: @Reid In ASP.NET Core, yes. What about WPF, UWP, WinForms, Xamarin, ... did I miss the ASP.NET core tag somewhere here?

Comment: @SirRufo, I see you are indeed correct: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31017#issuecomment-494557390 Thank you.

Comment: @Reid could you please share some piece of code for upload video after creation on vimeo? Thanks

Comment: @surendraKandira, I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to display a vimeo video that you have posted to vimeo? Or how to download a video that has been posted to vimeo?